# Visual Basic 6 causes Visual Studio 2010 to attempt an installation

Tags: vb6, visual-studio-2010

I'm using Visual Basic 6 for a legacy project and it's been working fine. I recently installed the Visual Studio 2010 RC and now when I start VB6 I get an installer with the title "Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional RC - ENU". If I click Cancel I can then open my project in VB6.

Is there any way of getting rid of this, or am I just the only person on the planet still using VB6?

Update: The fix worked for ages but the problem started happening again a week or so ago. Has anyone else seen this reappear?

Update to the update: I had my PC setup as dual boot between Win7 and WinXP. It seems some required files were on the WinXP drive, and when I deleted it recently it caused the problem to reappear.

Comment: You're not the only one! But I installed VB6 on a VM in case something like this might happen...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a [known problem](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/454051/opening-a-vb6-project-initiates-some-visual-studio-2010-configuration-operation).  Apparently Office apps can cause the same behavior.  Like you, I saw it when I opened a VB6 project.  It's still not fixed in the RC, but there is a workaround.  You just have to create a directory and the problem will go away.

> We've seen similar issues fixed by
>   determining which directory VS expects
>   to be created and then creating it.
>   We’ve fixed this in our RTMRel product
>   and the Visual Studio tools for office
>   team has put an additional test to
>   check for project. To work around this
>   issue try creating the following
>   directory. Open an elevated command
>   prompt and type the following command
>   and then open project again. Let me
>   know if this fixes the issue.
>
> Md "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft
>   Visual Studio
>   10.0\common7\IDE\FromGAC"

I also encountered this problem with the Visual Studio 2005 installer.  The solution was a bit more tedious, but I eventually got it to stop.

I found [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2009/05/29/how-to-work-around-the-issue-when-opening-office-applications-repairs-visual-studio) that said to look at the MsiInstaller warnings in the application event log.  There were two errors every time.  First an error with event ID 1004 that describes the problem.  This was followed by another error with event ID 1001 which was of no use.  I just created every file and folder it named in the 1004 errors and the problem went away.  I was getting ready to give up because I had no idea how many files it was going to complain about, but I kept at it and finally got it to stop.  These files contain nothing.  I just created new text files with my file manager and renamed them.  Here's what I had to create.

- `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\al.exe`
- `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\al.exe.config`
- `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Microsoft.Build.Conversion.dll`
- `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Microsoft.VisualBasic.xml`
- `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Microsoft.VisualStudio.VSHelp80.xml`
- `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Microsoft.Vsa.xml`
- `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\SQLServer.targets`
- `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Configuration.Install.xml`
- `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\RedistList`
- `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\RedistList\VSList.xml`

Comment: Thanks, that fixes it (although the command given is incorrect).

Comment: I have tried all the fixes on the internet that require no manual file modifications with no solution (including reinstalling both vb6 and vs 2008 and their service packs). However, creating an empty file named C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\RedistList\VSList.xml solved my issue!

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

1. Run VB6
2. Cancel the VS2010 installation.
3. Uncheck the "Visual Component Manager"

Source:

[After VS2010, SP1, VB6 launches VS2010 installer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d8b5c8bb-fdb4-4466-9d6d-1bb5d2fb0e95/after-vs2010-sp1-vb6-launches-vs2010-installer?forum=vssetup)

Comment: In my case I had to uncheck a different Add-In: Visual Build Pro Add-In

Answer (score 0):

I have been working over three days, I have installed visual studio 2015 and 2017. I resolved it by uninstalling Microsoft Visual studio 2010 Shell Integrated and install Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Shell isolated. IT will surely resolve an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had Vb6 and Visual studio 2017 on my machine. after a windows update, I started experiencing the problem when attempting to load Vb6. I uninstalled Visual studio 2017 and Vb6 loaded without error and my solutions are running okay.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note you are answering a very old and already answered question. Here is a guide on [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If anyone have monit for *"Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Shell (isolated) ENU"*, you can get it from SQL Server 2012 DVD or SQL Server 2012 Express e.g.

Required package is included in SQL Server 2012 in path

```
1033_ENU_LP\\redist\\VisualStudioShell\\VSSetup\\*.*
```

SQL Server 2012 Express (`2012ExprSP1_SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe`): when start instalation SQL, you can see the tmp folder name where files are unpacked. Then after starting VB6 and starting installation VS2010 Shell, wait for monit on installation source, then you can click "*Browse*" and select path *1033_ENU_LP\redist\VisualStudioShell\VSSetup\* from  unpacked SQL Server 2012 tmp folder.

(I know that over 10 years have passed. But believe me. People still run into this problem.)

Answer (score 0):

I know that we are in 2021 now, but the described problem started to hit me on my Windows 10 Enterprise system after the February 2021 Windows Update!

I am using a VB6 IDE and Visual Studio 2017. But looking to the Control Panel, there were also some VS 2010 products shown: VS 2010, both isolated and integrated, and VSTO 2010. I de-installed all of them, and my problem with the VB6 IDE was gone.

Answer (score -2):

You may as well be :)

VS 2010 runtime DLLs see you're running some way outdated version of something and wants to be helpful and update that to the current version.
Installing 2 versions of essentially the same tool on the same machine (especially tools as interwoven with the OS as VS) is generally a bad idea if you want both to function correctly and this is a side effect of that.

Comment: Not sure it's that simple - I haven't had any problems running VB6 and VS2008, and VS2010 seems quite happy when I run VS2008.